# TLA+ Trouble removing an element

Tags: tla+

Currently learning TLA+ and have gotten stuck on this simple method to remove a person from a register. Issue seems to be with the permission state from what I can see.

My TLA+ function looks like this and removes a person from the register along with the permissions.

```
DeRegister(p) == 
/\ p \in register
/\ register' = register \ {p}
/\ permission' = [x \in DOMAIN permission \ {p} |-> permission[x]]
/\ UNCHANGED <<location>>
```

My typeok that I'm checking against has the following constraints

```
TypeOk 
    /\ register \subseteq PERSON
    /\ permission \in [register -> SUBSET BUILDING]
    /\ location \in [register -> (BUILDING \union {OUTSIDE})]
```

I get a model error that typeOK is violated. In the stack trace the error looks like this

```
/\  location = [p1 |-> OUTSIDE]
/\  permission = << >>
/\  register = {}
```

Thanks for any insight

EDIT:

Previous state may be of some use which was

```
/\  location = [p2 |-> OUTSIDE]
/\  permission = [p2 |-> {}]
/\  register = {"p2"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location \in [register -> SUBSET BUILDING]` means (among other things) that `DOMAIN location = register`. After `DeRegister`, though, you have `DOMAIN location = {"pq"} /\ register = {}`, which violates your invariant.